# Relativity on a universal scale

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, cosmology, relativity

Imagine there was a clock on a planet the same size as earth, travelling at the same speed through space, and that this planet was at the most distant part of the universe from earth. If we had a telescope on earth which could observe that clock, what would we observe relative to a clock on earth?

Would we observe the distant clock to be running slower, faster or at the same speed than an earth clock?

Would the ticks of the distant clock relative to the earth clock be accelerating, decelerating or neither?

EDIT: I'm wondering in a universe with accelerated expansion, whether we would expect to observe time dilation effects. as a result in relative speed, or weakening gravitational fields.

Comment: I've only got 1st year uni physics under my belt and that was over 20 years ago.  I have some understanding of relativity and how that might come into play in the answering of this question.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit weird because from that distance, the photons would take so long to come back, I am not even sure a whole species could survive long enough to see one photon come back. You have to realize that even for the Sun, as relatively close as it is, photons take on average 8min 20sec to arrive. So you're always seeing the Sun as it was over 8mins ago. And even worse, this clock does not emit light, so we would have to send photons from here and wait for them to come back from "the most distant part of the universe" which sounds like a long way.

However, let's assume that we somehow got past this and have a way to get a "live feed" from another end of the universe (maybe quantum entanglement, or tachyons, who cares this is a thought experiment now). If the clock is built the same way that it is built here and classical mechanics applies near the surface of this planet where we place the clock (*i.e.* we are not near something like a black hole) you should just see it tick normally, because a clock is just a mechanical or electronic device and its reading is purely based on physical phenomena.

**Edit:** If you are trying to observe how time "passes" in that region of space, you would be better off observing the star around which this planet orbits. From our perspective, times/cycles are basically set by the sun, so it's possible that some species on this planet would do the same.

Comment: I'm wondering whether we would expect to observe time dilation effects, and how that would relate to observations of distant objects in the universe

Comment: Yes, more than likely. Time dilation even occurs from the Earth's surface up to satellites, so there are actually algorithms built in so satellites will know the Earth's time and vice-versa. @Mick

Comment: So you are changing your answer?  Are you now saying we wouldn't observe the clocks to be measuring time at the same rate?

Comment: You just now mentioned time dilation, there would be time dilation, nut no difference in the operation of the clocks.

Comment: In general, time dilation is experienced with clocks of different acceleration. So even your head ages slower than your toes for example.

Comment: You might also take into account that you would be observing a clock that is billions of years younger than the clock on earth. accounting for the time it takes for the light to travel from the clock to earth.